# Modificar todas las ids que contengan cierto texto dentro de su nombre

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla donde cada uno de sus elementos td tienen una id en este formato:

```
<td id="random123random"></td>
```

donde "random" puede ser cualquier cosa (aunque del mismo largo) y lo único que ciertas ids tienen en común, es el número "123" del medio.

Lo que necesito es seleccionar todas las td que contengan ese 123 del medio para cambiarlo por un "456".

Supongo que en JQuery debería haber una forma de crear un selector que haga lo que quiero, con el objetivo de tener algo como:

```
(a modo demostrativo) nueva = "idQueConserveEltextoDeLosExtremosperoCambie123por456"
$("idQueContenga123enElmedio").attr("id", nueva);
```

Entonces ahora que lo veo, se me hace complejo fijar las nuevas ids, pues cuando se las reasigne a cada td, deben conservar el texto random de los extremos y solo cambiar el número "123" del medio por un "456".

Gracias por su tiempo.

**EDIT**

Disculpen si me expresé mal, pero cuando dije "seleccionar todas las ids que..." no me refería a algún tipo de consulta para base de datos, son simplemente las ids de la tabla que mencioné al principio, son ids que están siendo trabajadas con jquery solo en el frontend.

Comment: con qué tecnología estás trabajando en el backend?

Comment: jquery, si a eso te refieres por tecnología.

Comment: jquery -> frontend. backend: PHP, Java, C#, u otro?

Comment: estás utilizando algun 3rd party como DevExpress, Telerik?

Comment: PHP. .,.,.,.,--

Comment: revisen el EDIT por favor.

Comment: Disculpen si demoré mucho en puntuar las respuestas, tardé un tanto en aplicar la respuesta de Dev. Joel y funcionó a la perfección.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como menciono @Leandro usar `*=` para implementar un `Like` y para cambiar el id lo haría por medio de la función [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```
$('tr [id*="123"]').attr('id', function(_, id) {
   return id.replace('123', '456');
});
```

Según la documentación [Pasar function a attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, muchas gracias! Grande!

Comment: No conocía esa manera de pasar la función que usaste allí, tienes alguna documentación en donde pueda investigar para aprender más al respecto?

Comment: En La documentación de JQuery está http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

Comment: gracias, y el guión bajo qué significa o dónde reviso documentación de eso?

Comment: Ahí en en enlace está , el   `_`  sólo es un nombre de variable en este caso solo es un parametro de una función que podría ser cualquier otra y no afectará nada el funcionamiento

Answer (score 1):

Si usas jquery para seleccionar los elementos por medio del `*=`

[Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

podrias seleccionar aplicando un `like` en la busqueda

```
$("[Id*='123']").each(function(){

   $(this).attr('id', 'valor');

});
```

[.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: y cómo conservo el texto de los extremos de cada id?

Comment: revisa el EDIT por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para encontrar ID's específicos gracias a una expresión regular, de la siguiente forma:

```
var match = $('td').filter(function(){
    return this.id.match(/123/);
  });
```

Donde el 123 es lo que quieres encontrar, para luego modificarlo como mencionaron arriba con .each de jQuery:

```
match.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id','test');
  });
```

Si deseas conservar los extremos de cada string, y sabes que el ID será siempre numérico puedes guardarlo en la función del .each() con otra expresión regular en la que guardas en un Array todo lo que no sea numérico (asumiendo que el ID siempre será un número):

```
match.each(function(){
    var prev = $(this).attr('id').match(/[^0-9]{2,}/g);
    var concat = prev[0] + 999 + prev[1];
    console.log("concat: " + concat);
    $(this).attr('id',concat);
  });
```

Hice un ejemplo aquí http://codepen.io/akh000/pen/ALJvvo